# PlayFramework, custom logging configuration with xml

Tags: playframework, logback

I use 2.3.6 play framework and i have set up logging output with custom xml configuration file.

Here it is:

```
<conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${user.dir}/logs/application.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- Daily rollover with compression -->
        <fileNamePattern>application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 30 days worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>

<logger name="play" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

<logger name="application" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

<logger name="actors" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="models" level="DEBUG"/>

<logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
<logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
<logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />
<logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />
<logger name="com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport" level="OFF"/>
```

With that configuration i have doubled output lines, i mean:

```
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql://1.1.1.1/project.dev
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql://1.1.1.1/project.dev
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

Could you explain me why?

I don't get what's difference between play logger and application logger.
I think hierarchy is rootLogger -> playLogger -> applicationLogger -> my loggers.

```
package actors

import akka.actor.Props
import play.api.Logger

object MainCtrl {

  val log = Logger("actors.stat.MainCtrl")
```

I don't understand why play and application logger can't be just one logger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that one is the Logger of the framework "Play" (you do not control the output of this, you just can set the level) and the other is the Logger of your actual application.

Try removing the appender from the "play" logger.

Answer (score 0):

the reason for duplicate of lines in output file is Appenders accumulation.
accourding to logback configuration document :

> By default, appenders are cumulative: a logger will log to the appenders attached to itself (if any) as well as all the appenders attached to its ancestors. Thus, attaching the same appender to multiple loggers will cause logging output to be duplicated.